# "The process cannot access the file X because it is used by another process" - C#

Tags: c#, console-application, .net

I am getting the "The process cannot the file X because it is being used by another process" when I execute the following piece of code in my console application:

```
List<string> lines1 = new List<string>();
List<string> lines2 = new List<string>();

string path1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("path1");
string path2 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("path2");

File.Create(path1);
File.Create(path2);

foreach (object myObject in myObjects)
{
   //do some fancy logic here!!!
}

File.WriteAllLines(path1, lines1.ToArray());  //exception is thrown here
File.WriteAllLines(path2, lines2.ToArray());
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Doesn't the `File.Create(..)` method return a `FileStream`? Do your writing on that rather than a different method, then `.Close()` it properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The likely problem here is the `File.Create` method.  It's creating and returning a handle to the file in question wrapped in a `FileStream` object.  That object is holding the file open for write and is hence blocking your later `File.WriteAllLines` call.

The simplest solution is to remove the `File.Create` calls.  Just let the `WriteAllLines` method create the file for you

Answer (score 1):

You have two options: File.Create not only creates the file but OPENS it. so you need to keep a reference to the filestream and close it like this:

```
         var file1 = File.Create(path1);
         var file2 = File.Create(path2);
         file1.Close();
         file2.Close();
```

OR you can just skip that because `File.WriteAllLines(...)` will create a file if it doesn't already exist.

You probably want to leverage something like File.Exist to prevent other exceptions, but that is not part of the present question.

Answer (score 0):

File.Create(path1) is opening and keeping the file open and hence locking it.

File.WriteAllLines will create the file , so there is no need to create it first.

If you need to create it first (eg to test the path) you can do

```
    FileStream fs = File.Create(path1);
    fs.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment above, `File.Create(..)` returns a `FileStream` object, which won't be destroyed until the method is closed (which means the handle is still open, thus file is still locked). When you're trying to use `WriteAllLines` it's attempting to open a new handle, and failing because one's already open.

You can use code like the following, which works fine (just tested):

```
List<string> lines1 = new List<string>();
string path1 = @"C:\Development\test1.txt";
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    lines1.Add("Test " + i);

TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(File.Create(path1));
foreach(string line in lines1)
    textWriter.WriteLine(line);
textWriter.Close();
```

The code above will utilise the same stream that was created when the file was created, so you have no chance of collision.

Alternatively as in other answers, the `File.WriteAllLines` method will create the file for you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the File.Create lines, you should be fine.  Unless you're doing something with the files in your foreach loop, you don't need to call the File.Create methods at all.  The File.WriteAllLines will create a file if it doesn't exist.  Since the File.WriteAllLines method also closes the filestream, you don't have to worry about managing the filestream returned by a File.Create.